# Calculate the working hour

Tags: vb.net

I find it difficult to get the actual working `hour` and `minute` based on the `Pay Amount` and `Pay rate` per `hour`.

Example : `working duration = (wages / pay per hour)`

The following is my code. Please help.

```
    strActDuration = CStr(Math.Round((dblActual / dblPayAmount), 1))


                            Dim parts As String() = strActDuration.Split("."c)
                            Dim strhour As Integer = 0
                            Dim strminutes As Integer = 0


                            If parts.Length = 1 Then
                                strhour = Integer.Parse(parts(0))
                                strminutes = 0
                            ElseIf parts.Length = 2 Then
                                strhour = Integer.Parse(parts(0))
                                strminutes = Integer.Parse(parts(1))
                                'strroundminutes = CInt(Math.Round(strminutes, 3))
                                'strroundminutes = CInt(Math.Truncate(strminutes / 10))

                            End If

                            strCombineDuration = strhour & "Hr " & strminutes & "Min"
```

Comment: You tagged it `sql` and `sql-server` but your question doesn't have any sql information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the duration as a number (double) and work in minutes; convert to Hours/Minutes using .NET formats:

```
dblMinutes = Math.Round(60*dblActual/dblPayAmount, 1)
Dim ts as TimeSpan = New Timespan(0, dblMinutes, 0)
strDuration = Format(ts.Hours, "0") & " Hr " & Format(ts.Minutes, "0")) & " Min"
```

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as correct to improve the next persons results.